# Black rectangle at corner of wevbiew kindle fire hd 7 inch device?

Tags: android, webview, kindle-fire

[image]

Can you able to figure out what's wrong with this webview on kindle fire?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting

```
mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
```

it's a shot in the dark, but I've had some strange WebView drawing problems solved by disabling hardware acceleration.

Comment: Thank you very much smith, it's work. also i have one another problem webview showing one popup type view, on click on one tab, but it showing blank screen..can you figure out this issue?

Comment: i have added screen shot of popup, it showing on browser but not showing on application, i am loading url of mobile site in webview